# C# unit test n-tier mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am new to Unit testing. I didn't found a complete example/sample of unit testing a CRUD application.

I want to add unit test in MVC application which is using entity framework.

Do we actually add data in database everytime we run a test? 
Do we create seperate unit test projects for every project?

Comment: Unit tests are verifying for small pieces of your app. You do not unit test your data access code. Instead you mock it (store/read data from memory instead of an actual db). You can create integration tests which does the end to end testing (including a real database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unit tests should be fast
- Unit tests should be executed in isolation of other application's units
- Unit tests should be executed in isolation of other tests

Using database in unit tests will violate "principles" above

- Accessing database is slow
- Database represents "global state" of your application - so using same database will force you to setup and clear database for every tests and remove possibility to run tests in parallel.

For unit tests you need abstract everything which make tests slow or depend on global state.
In your case will be enough to abstract only database operations and mock it in the tests.
Entity Framework Core provide nice [In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/), where you can write fast unit tests which will tests database operations too.

For writing tests with mocked database you need to configure mock object to return or assert expected data for your tests.
If you use `InMemory` database provider you will need to insert data for tests or read database for asserting expected result.

Having own test project for every "tested" project is common practice, but feel free to invent your own structure of your solution, which will fit your needs and expectations. Main idea that you will be able quickly find correspondent tests for some of the behavior or concrete method.